# Remove elements from a subgroup

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following string, I need to santize the zero elements inside the array, I must use regex for some reasons, because the scripting language I'm using I can't serialize/deserialize I have only a regex engine.

String:

```
{
   "admins": [0, 148, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   "auth": "30639096bfe4ec4b9f17696ef1d02b9a",
}
```

and output a string like:

```
{
   "admins": [148],
   "auth": "30639096bfe4ec4b9f17696ef1d02b9a",
}
```

or eventually, if are all zero:

```
{
   "admins": [],
   "auth": "30639096bfe4ec4b9f17696ef1d02b9a",
}
```

Currently my pattern is:

```
(?<=admins":[[:space:]]\[)(.*(,[[:space:]]0))(?=\])
```

I can't find the correct way to remove the subgroup data, actually I'm here: https://regex101.com/r/4yRSCn/1

Comment: Is it not a json ?

Comment: So, is it a .NET regex engine? If yes, why use regex101 that does not fully support it?

Comment: For the downvoter, read the question I can't treat is as a JSON (as it is, I know)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, but I have only it in a scripting console

Comment: .NET regex does not support POSIX character classes.

Comment: Try `(?<="admins":\s*\[[^][]*?)\s*,?\s*\b0\b,?\s*`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22admins%22%3a%5cs*%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%3f%29%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%5cb0%5cb%2c%3f%5cs*&i=%22admins%22%3a+%5b0%2c+148%2c+10%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%5d%2c%0d%0a%22admins%22%3a+%5b0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%2c+0%5d%2c&r=)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You loss comma in case `...10, 0, 5,...`

Comment: Then `(?<="admins":\s*\[[^][]*?)(?:(?<=\[)0(?:,\s*0\b)*,?|\s*,\s*0\b\s*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a regex with .NET regex engine, you may leverage its infinite-length lookbehind pattern feature.

```
(?<="admins":\s*\[[^][]*?)(?:(?<=\[)0(?:,\s*0\b)*,?|\s*,\s*0\b\s*)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%22admins%22%3A%5Cs*%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%3F%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%290%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cs*0%5Cb%29*%2C%3F%7C%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*0%5Cb%5Cs*%29&i=%22admins%22%3A%20%5B0%2C%20148%2C%2010%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%22admins%22%3A%20%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%0D%0A%22admins%22%3A%20%5B0%2C%20148%2C%200%2C%2010%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C&r=).

Output:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<="admins":\s*\[[^][]*?)` - since you only want to remove `0`s inside square brackets after `"admins":[` substring, this positive lookebhind is meant to check that condition, the current position must be immediately preceded with:

  - `"admins":` - a literal substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^][]*?` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `(?:` - start of an alternation group:

  - `(?<=\[)` - a `[` must immediately precede the current location
  - `0` - a zero
  - `(?:,\s*0\b)*` - zero or more repetitions of `,`, 0+ whitespaces, `0` and a word boundary
  - `,?` - an optional comma
- `|` - or

  - `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with optional 0+ whitespaces
  - `0` - a zero
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `)` - end of an alternation group

This alternation group is necessary to differentiate between zeros at the start of the bracketed substring and those after, so that the commas and whitespace is removed consistently.

Comment: Great answer and explaination

Comment: Could you explain `[^][]*?` part - I really don't get it.

Comment: @JohnyL `[^...]`  is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it matches any char that is not a char defined in the class. Since `]` and `[` are inside the negated character class, `[^][]` matches a char other than `[` and `]`. The `*?`  is a lazy quantifier, that makes the pattern it modifies match 0 or more chars, as few as possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I know this. I meant *why* did you use it? What was the goal of it?

Comment: @JohnyL Make sure we match all the 0 numbers between square brackets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah! Now I got that. The first look-behind is about to match everything from the closing `]` to the left and the alternation is just about edge cases. BTW, correct *...look**eb**hind is meant...* 